# Get object based on number id

Tags: java, jaxb

I want to get specific XML configuration based on unique id:

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<environment name="qa">
    <configuration>
        <url>test</url>
        <username>test</username>
        <password>test!</password>
        <tests>
            <test number = "123" name = "test">
                <lp_number = "123"/>
            </test>
            <test number = "564" name = "test">
                <lp_number = "1233333"/>
            </test>
        </tests>
    </configuration>
</environment>
```

JAXB object:

```
    public class Configuration {
    
        @XmlElement(name = "url", required = true)
        String url;
    
        @XmlElement(name = "username", required = true)
        String username;
    
        @XmlElement(name = "password", required = true)
        String password;
            
        @XmlElement(name = "tests", required = true)
        Tests tests;
    }

@Getter
@Setter
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Tests {

    @XmlElement(name = "test", required = true)
    private List<Test> test;

}

@Getter
@Setter
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Test {

    @XmlAttribute
    private Integer number;

}

String fileName = "settings.xml";
        ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();
        File file = new File(classLoader.getResource(fileName).getFile());
        JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Environment.class);

        Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
        env = (Environment) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(file);
```

The question is how to get the configuration based on number id?
I would like to get only the object for number = "564".

```
<test number = "564" name = "test">
   <lp_number = "1233333"/>
</test>
```

Comment: can't you use env and search deeper for the object that satisfy your need?

Comment: Can you show me how please?

Answer (score 1):

```
@XmlRootElement
public class Environment {

        @XmlElement(name = "configuration", required = true)
        Configuration configuration;

       ...getters
}

@Getter
@Setter
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Test {

    @XmlAttribute
    private Integer number;

    @XmlAttribute(name = "number")
    Integer num;

}
```

Then the following should give you an instance of Environment

```
        ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();
        File file = new File(classLoader.getResource(fileName).getFile());
        JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Environment.class);

        Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
        env = (Environment) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(file);
```

So you can search that instance

```
  Configuration conf = env.getConfiguration();
    List<Test> tests = conf.getTests();
    for ( Test test : tests ) {
      if(test.getNum() == 564) {
        System.out.println("Found!");
    }
   }
```